# How to update custom Excel ribbon

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, ribbon

I need update custom Excel ribbon of working file without closing file from another Excel file.

I try make this task using Open XML SDK for Office.

Here class that export and import custom ribbon.

```
public static class OpenDocumentTools
{
    public static bool ExportCustomRibbon(string fileName, string exportDir)
    {
        try
        {
            //Get RibbonExtensibilityPart
            SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, true);
            RibbonExtensibilityPart ribbon = spreadsheetDocument.RibbonExtensibilityPart;

            //Clear directory
            foreach (string fil in Directory.EnumerateFiles(exportDir).ToList())
                File.Delete(fil);

            //Processing images
            foreach (ImagePart imagePart in ribbon.ImageParts.ToList())
            {
                Image img = Image.FromStream(imagePart.GetStream());
                string[] arrPath = imagePart.Uri.OriginalString.Split(new char[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                string imageName = arrPath[arrPath.Length - 1];
                img.Save(string.Format("{0}\\{1}", exportDir, imageName));
            }

            //Save ribbon xml
            StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(string.Format("{0}\\Ribbon.xml", exportDir));
            sw.WriteLine(ribbon.CustomUI.OuterXml);
            sw.Close();

            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public static bool ImportCustomRibbon(string fileName, string xmlFile, string importDir)
    {
        try
        {
            //Read xml content
            string content = File.OpenText(xmlFile).ReadToEnd();

            using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, true))
            {
                //Get or create RibbonExtensibilityPart
                RibbonExtensibilityPart ribbon = document.RibbonExtensibilityPart;
                if (ribbon == null)
                    ribbon = document.AddRibbonExtensibilityPart();

                //Load xml content to ribbon
                ribbon.CustomUI = new CustomUI(content);
                ribbon.CustomUI.Save();

                //Remove image parts
                foreach (ImagePart imagePart in ribbon.ImageParts.ToList())
                    ribbon.DeletePart(imagePart);

                //Load images to ribbon
                foreach (string fileNam in Directory.EnumerateFiles(importDir).ToList())
                {
                    ImagePart imagePart = null;
                    switch (Path.GetExtension(fileNam))
                    {
                        case ".png":
                            imagePart = ribbon.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Png, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileNam));
                            break;
                        case ".jpeg":
                            imagePart = ribbon.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Jpeg, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileNam));
                            break;
                        default:
                            continue;
                    }

                    if (imagePart != null)
                    {
                        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileNam, FileMode.Open))
                        {
                            stream.Position = 0;
                            imagePart.FeedData(stream);
                        }

                        ribbon.AddPart(imagePart, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileNam));
                    }

                }
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here calling code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool res = OpenDocumentTools.ExportCustomRibbon(@"D:\15\Ribbon\Source.xlsm", @"D:\15\Ribbon\Export");

    res = OpenDocumentTools.ImportCustomRibbon(@"D:\15\Ribbon\Dest.xlsm", @"D:\15\Ribbon\Export\Ribbon.xml", @"D:\15\Ribbon\Export");
}
```

When Excel-files are closed, code working fine. But if Excel-file is open, I have exception: 
"The process cannot access the file 'D:\15\Ribbon\Dest.xlsm' because it is being used by another process.” This is occurred, when programm trying execute “using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, true))”.

Does anybody know what way I can use for updating ribbon without closing file?